# Passing a pointer to an array in a constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need to pass a pointer to an array in a constructor (I am aware that using plain arrays in C++ is considered by many as bad practice, but for now I just want to go ahead with it).

Please consider the following code:

```
// let's omit includes

class A {
   // irrelevant
}

class B {
    public:
    //irrelevant
    void someMethod() {
        _c = new C(array_id);
    }

    private:
    C* _c;
    A* array_id[SOME_CONST];
}

class C {
    public:
    C(A* a_array) : _array(a_array) {}
    private:
    A* _array;
}
```

Trying to compile will result in a:

```
error: no matching function for call to C::C(A* [SOME_CONST])'
```

As far as I know, the identifier of an array decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, but it seems that it cannot be used directly. How can I effectively pass a pointer to an array of A* in the constructor of C?

Comment: It looks like you are passing an array of pointers where a pointer is expected.

Comment: Right, the identifier for the array decays into a pointer to the first element of the array. The first element of the array is an `A*`, so a pointer to that is an `A**`, and you don't have a constructor that accepts an `A**`.

Comment: @immibis Why would the identifier for the array decay here? There's nothing it can decay to.

Comment: _@roymcclure_ Shouldn't this `A* array_id[SOME_CONST];` be `A array_id[SOME_CONST];`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Why do you think it can't decay to a pointer to its first element?

Comment: @immibis Because the first element is a pointer. And the function parameter is not a pointer to a pointer. The array can't decay to `A*`.

Comment: @juanchopanza s/decays/would decay/ then, if it bothers you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> 4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion [conv.array]
>   An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted
>   to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the
>   first element of the array.

Modify your code like this:

```
   class C {

        public:
        typedef A* PTA[SOME_CONST];
        C(PTA a_array) : _array(a_array) {}
        private:
        A** _array;//Note this line,type decays.
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems: The first is that you're calling the `C` constructor with an array *of pointers*, not an array. The second problem is that you're trying to assign that allocation to an incompatible type.

Solution *might* be something like

```
class B
{
public:
    void someMethod()
    {
        my_c = new C(my_a_array);
    }

private:
    A my_a_array[SOME_CONST];
    C* my_c;
};
```

That will allocate a *single* object of type `C`, passing the *array* of `A` objects to it.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I effectively pass a pointer to an array of A* in the constructor of C?

```
C(array_id);
```

The problem is that the `C` constructor doesn't accept an array of `A*`, it accepts an `A*`.

If you want to pass an array of `A*` to the `C` constructor then you need to declare it to take an `A**`:

```
C(A** a_array)
```

Or, equivalently:

```
C(A* a_array[])
```